# Be-conditional for hypothetic past, present or future

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it right that the "**Be-conditional**" can be used to speak about hypothetic past, present or future?

- Be it my car I would have sold it.
- Be it my car I would sell it.
- Be it my car I will sell it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a few common contemporary expressions that use the "be-conditional":

> Be it ever so humble there's no place like home.
>
> Be that as it may.
>
> Far be it from me to ...
>
> Be it resolved/enacted ... (legislative jargon)

and possibly a few others.  Otherwise the grammar is archaic and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

This was a surprisingly interesting question for me to stumble across, so here goes. The simple, straightforward answer is that none of these are correct, though the last one is closest to correct (but not really).

The first two would be better expressed with `were` replacing `be` (and also adding a comma between the two parts of the sentence):

- **Were** it my car, I would have sold it
- **Were** it my car, I would sell it

The last sentence doesn't really work by replacing *Be* with *Were*; I don't have a formal explanation as to why this is, though perhaps it's because *were* is a hypothetical and *will* is definitive.

The reason that I said that the last sentence was kinda correct is that in older forms of English, there is a form of the present subjunctive that was used: "Do you know *if it be* raining, or no?" which is similar to the last sentence, reformulated. (If it be my car, I will sell it).

However, that's an archaic, old usage, and you would get very strange looks if you used it nowadays